# How do I start emacs in the upper right hand corner of my Windows display?

Tags: windows, emacs, emacs24

Back in my Unix days, I used to be able to start Emacs in the top right corner of my screen by specifying a `geometry` option on startup.  However, if I use

```
C:\Emacs\emacs-24.2\bin\runemacs.exe -geometry 80x60-0+0 --debug-init
```

on Windows7, the Emacs window does not stay in the top-right.  It does appear to be top right briefly, then the window resizes as Emacs initializes, and shifts out of the top-right corner.  It appears that the resize is due to the specification of a font, because when I comment out the following line in my .emacs, the window stays in the top right.

```
(set-default-font "-*-Courier New-normal-r-*-*-12-90-*-*-c-*-*-ansi-")
```

Does anybody know how I can force Emacs into the top right corner of the screen (besides using the default font).  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible solutions

1. Specify the font on the command line so it is not processed after the geometry option.

`runemacs -fn "Courier New-9" -geometry 80x60-0+0 --debug-init`

1. Specify the geometry in .emacs after the font is changed (-0 does not work in this context, as the sign is discarded by the lisp parser).

`(setq initial-frame-alist '((top . 0) (left . -1) (width . 80) (height . 60)))`

Comment: Cheers!  Both solutions work.  Thanks for the good explanation, too.

Comment: It can be `(left . (- 0))`, thus avoiding the 1 pixel gap.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `-0+0` for the upper right hand corner?  That does the trick for me using Emacs 21.3.

Comment: You're right about the -0+0.  I updated the question, since the window still doesn't stay all the way to the right.